# php math algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, math

Sorry it haven't occurred to me a better title :).

So I have two buttons that increase or decreases the decimal value of `$page` by 1, the problem is that I need to call external data whom paging system starts with 5 and adds 15 to change to next page, so `$page`'s value don't apply.

The question is: how can I change $page's values from 1, 2, 3, 4... to 5, 20, 35, 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$start = 5;
$step = 15;
$result = $start + ($page-1) * $step;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `5 + (n - 1) * 15` as page number, n = 1, 2, 3, ...